# After entering the password and hitting enter the screen is blurred

Tags: boot, 20.04, login, screen, login-screen

Ubuntu boots normally and reaches the login screen. After entering the password and hitting enter, screen goes blurred. Is there any way to troubleshoot this problem?

[image: Photo of the screen]

Comment: Did you change anything recently?

Comment: No, but it got stuck at login page, so i pressed power button to shut it down